# Object oriented programming question

Tags: jquery

In order to empty the contents of a table cell, I issue the following command:

```
$('td').empty()
```

but to empty the contents of an input field, I say:

```
$('input').val() -- Edit: .val('')
```

Q: Doesn't this go against the idea of object oriented programming?  Wouldn't you have the same method for each which means "Whatever you need to do to empty yourself, you now have my permission to do so"?

Like, if you have a cat.speak and a dog.speak and the cat meows and the dog barks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that these operations are doing two very different things.

- `empty` is removing HTML content from the target element(s).
- `val` is setting the value of a form element, at least when it is used with an argument.

So I think it is fine that two differently-named functions are specified.

For what it's worth, jQuery is written in a prototypical/functional style, not OO, but that does not change your original question.

Comment: can you justify functional style? The heart of jQuery is `$.fn` which is all about prototypical inheritance

Comment: @JustinEithier "jQuery allows you to write functional code" and "the jQuery code is functional" are disjoint

Answer (score 7):

1: jQuery is **NOT** OOP and never claimed to be
2: `$('input').val()` just returns the value of the input, it does not `empty` it out
3: `$('td').empty()` removes html content. It is not made to "empty" out any input element, to empty an input you would do: `$('input').val('')`

Answer (score 2):

Your confusing **removing HTML content** and **setting a value to null.**

you never **remove text content from an input**. The browser removes it for you due to it being data bound.

`$("input").val("")` does not empty the input.

The fact that `.val("")` removes text content from an input is a mere side effect that the text in an input field is **data bound** to the `value` property of the `<input>`.

Your generalizing too much.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you do empty you are cleaning everything in between a `<td>` and a `</td>`.

When you do .val('') you are setting the value attribute of the input field to empty.

```
<input type="text" value="hi"/>
```

Two diferent things.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, they do entirely separate things.

`.empty()` removes *all* descendents of the specified node.

`.val()` in fact *doesn't* empty the contents of an input field, it *returns* them.

Answer (score 1):

your empty and val are two different things .empty removes dom elements from the selector .val() gets the value of the input selector

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's going against OOP since `empty()` exists to clear all DOM children from the given parent. While `val()` exists for settings values on controls that display text in some way, like buttons, textboxes etc.

So, `td` can have many children and `empty()` makes all sense when clearing it. While a button only contais a text value, wich makes sense to modify that `val()`.

I think that here the OOP is ok.